# Laptop doesn't accept over 2GB of RAM anymore

Tags: laptop, memory

Lately I've been having issues with my Asus A75VM-TY087V laptop. Over a year ago I upgraded the 6GB (2GB+4GB) of RAM to 8GB (2x4GB), which worked fine so far. Just a while ago the laptop didn't consistently POST anymore, and after a long time of fiddling around I decided to get the original 2GB stick and plug it in, which works. So I expected both 4GB RAM sticks to be fried.

I've gotten 2 other 2GB RAM sticks, which all work perfectly in any of the two slots, however when combining them in any way (to get 4GB) POST doesn't happen consistently anymore. Only after leaving it on for a while the laptop will eventually do 'something', which is either: hang at POST logo, hang at Windows loading or even completely boot into Windows 10, which works perfectly afterwards. Exactly the same behaviour occurs when using one of the 4GB sticks, or even combining them for 8GB (which work a lot less often than any 4GB configuration).

All RAM sticks have been verified to work in another laptop.

I've not been able to find an answer to this problem yet, the only answers I can find are for laptops which never supported anything over 2GB (this setup ran fine for just over a year). I hope someone has an idea as to where I could look. The BIOS is up to date with the latest 234 build.

Edit:
I just installed the 2x4GB sticks again, and after approximately 2 minutes POST started, the laptop booted and it's fully functional now. I'm not able to consistently reproduce 'the problem', it just seems totally random.

It's a little over 3 years old, so I don't have any warranty anymore. Besides wanting to fix this issue I'm interested in why at once every 2GB combinations works perfectly, but anything above has problems like described above.

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS Upgrade>?

Comment: Contact Asus about it. I had a HP laptop with flaky support for RAM sizes above 2GB, and they pointed me to a specific bios to run.

Comment: @Harvey see my question. I've already done that. FrankThomas I've ran this BIOS for a long time and it just worked, only now after a year this problem occurs. I can try though.

Comment: Could it be a issue with RAM speeds? the new RAM you tried is it the same speed as the old sticks?

Comment: @Harvey The original 4GB modules and the 2GB module are 1600MHz. The two extra test sticks I got are 1066MHz. I don't think this is the problem though since the 2x4GB-1600MHz configuration has ran perfectly for over a year.

Comment: True, I would very much lean toward a motherboard issue then

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a flaky connection somewhere in the wiring on the motherboard.
It is possible that the problem comes and goes depending on temperature, stress on the housing (e.g what sort of surface the laptop is on when you use it), even how hard you hammer the keyboard or press on the touchpad may make a difference.
It's in most cases not possible or very difficult to diagnose something like this with 100% certainty.
And to make matters worse: This sort of problem usually gets worse over time. Making the laptop more and more unreliable.

I would first test all ram-strips individually in another computer using memtest86 and leave that running for at least 1 hour per stick. This to make sure the sticks themselves are OK.
Then test them (individually and in combinations) with the laptop. If this fails consistently the culprit has to be the motherboard, by elimination of anything else. In that case I hope for you it still under warranty.

If you can't reproduce the problem like this or if the warranty has run out... Time to start looking for another laptop. (At least, I presume you don't wish to continue working with a laptop that is unreliable and may get even worse over time.)

Comment: I can test at least every 2GB stick in this laptop (or other laptop), however I think that's just a waste of time. I've already checked all combinations, and as stated every 2GB 'combination' works instantly, every 4GB combi (2x2GB or 1x4GB) works sometimes, and the 8GB (2x4GB) combination works even less, indeed indicating a motherboard issue (a quick test (boot to Windows) in another laptop shows each stick&combination works fine). It doesn't fail consistently, that's what I'm most worried about. I don't often use this laptop anymore, only rare occurences for university. Warranty has voided.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it sounds like a motherboard issue.  If the RAM works fine in another laptop, then it is eliminated as the culprit.  Hopefully it is under warranty.  If not, you'll need a replacement motherboard or a replacement laptop.

Comment: The warranty has void already, it's just a little over 3 years old now. I wish I could just stick with my desktop but university requires me to have a laptop (even though I don't use it that often). So I guess I'll have to get a new laptop then :(